# Botframework Dialog migration v3 to v4

Tags: botframework

currently I'm trying to migrate my v3 bot to v4 and I'm a little stuck how to migrate the v3 `IDialog`. What is the equivalent in v4 and how to use them? Also, how can I do an Activity forwarding in v4? In v3 this would have been something like `await context.Forward(…)`?

Many Thanks & Best Regards
Fabian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good place to start when converting a V3 dialog to V4 involves changing:

`IDialog` `->` `Dialog` or `ComponentDialog` (depending)

`StartAsyc` `->` `BeginDialogAsync`

`MessageReceivedAsync` `->` `ContinueDialogAsync`

`IDialogContext` `->` `DialogContext`

The *Microsoft Bot Builder* V3 .net sdk used *AutoFac* extensively, and dialog stack was generally more invisible to developers than it is in *Bot Builder* V4.  V3 developers use .`Call` and .`Forward` to push dialogs onto the stack, and .`EndDialog` to pop them.  In V3, fields on dialogs are automatically serialized/deserialized and scoped to `PrivateConversationData`.  There was no need to configure dialog state specifically, the sdk added this for every bot and assumed the developer had registered a valid `IBotDataStore<BotData>` implementation with autofac.  Access to the `PrivateConversationData`, `ConversationData` and `UserData` is automatic from `IDialogContext`.

With *Bot Builder* V4, dialog stack and state setup is more in the hands of the developer.  Within the `BeginDialogAsync` and `ContinueDialogAsync` methods, the `DialogContext` has a `BeginDialogAsync` method that will start that dialog as a child of the current dialog (similar to `.Forward` in V3).  Resuming after a dialog completes, and utilizing the value returned from the child dialog, is different and involves using `DialogTurnResult.Result`

`DialogContext` also has references to the `TurnContext` and `DialogInstance` in V4 is the `dialogContext.ActiveDialog`.  From the `DialogInstance` you can retrieve the `DialogState` object, which is an `IDictionary<string, object>` implementation that is json serialized into/out of the store configured in *Startup.cs*  V4 retains the concepts of `UserData`, `ConversationData` and `PivateConversationData`.  Setup is a little different, but these data buckets are still scoped as they were:

- The user state creates a key using the channel ID and from ID.
  `{Activity.ChannelId}/users/{Activity.From.Id}#YourPropertyName`
- The conversation state creates a key using the channel ID and the conversation ID. 
  `{Activity.ChannelId}/conversations/{Activity.Conversation.Id}#YourPropertyName`
- The private conversation state creates a key using the channel ID, from ID and the conversation ID. 
  `{Activity.ChannelId}/conversations/{Activity.Conversation.Id}/users/{Activity.From.Id}#YourPropertyName`

State accessors are configured in Startup's `ConfigureServices` method.

Documentation assisting developers with this process of V3 to V4 bot and dialog migration is in the works.

Some links for further reading on v4 dialogs and state:

[Advanced conversation flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-dialog-manage-complex-conversation-flow)

[Gather user input using a dialog prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-prompts)

[Managing state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

[Save user and conversation data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)

[Implement custom storage for your bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-custom-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

Comment: Many Thanks for your great explanations, this helped me really a lot!