# New botframework-emulator and migrating bots question

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

Bot Framework Emulator is starting to nag me to upgrade to Version 4 and migrate my bots. I'm concerned about the migrating bots part. My bots are pretty complex and written in VS 2015, .Net 4.6.1. What does the new bot emulator want to migrate my bots to, I wonder, .Net Core? How much work will that be? How much work will I be looking at to upgrade the emulator and migrate my bots?

Answer (score 1):

A Bot built using **Microsoft Bot Builder SDK** V3 or V4 should work using either the V3 or V4 Emulator.  The SDK version does not need to match the Emulator version.

Also, you can install both the V3 Emulator and the V4 Emulator on the same box.

For V3 to V4 migration, please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53771296/86646

Comment: I installed V4, but it doesn't seem to be able to connect to my bot on localhost. The url looks correct in the live chat window - http://localhost:3979/api/messages - but I'm getting a 'couldn't send' message. I'm not seeing a login or 'connect' screen.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the Visual Studio output window while debugging locally?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the bot framework architecture for V3 and V4 is considerable. V4 runs on .Net Core and the way things need to be coded are changed a lot. You will need to invest some time first to check the new framework out.